# C# using streamwriter and streamreader at the same time to change line

Tags: c#

so i searched a lot about how to change specific line in file, so i found the code which deletes line. I managed to edit the code and it changes exact line, but when i want to change other line after, previous word resets, and I dont know why.

This is the code which i found:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\input")) {
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\output")) {
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
        if (String.Compare(line, line_to_delete) == 0)
            continue;

        writer.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

}

This is my edited code:

```
public void ChangeLineInFile(string file, string file2, string linetochange, string changedline) {
            string line = null;

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file)) {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file2)) {
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
                        if (String.Equals(line, linetochange)) {
                            writer.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", changedline));
                        } else {
                            writer.WriteLine(line);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            File.Delete(file);
            File.Move(file2, file);
            File.Delete(file2);
        }
```

Comment: do you mean you are calling ChangeLineFIle twice and that your first set of changes are being lost

Comment: `it changes exact line, but when i want to change other line after, previous word resets, and I dont know why.` <= I am not sure what this means. Please edit your question and provide some more detail, it would help if you described the current results and the expected results (as well as the difference if that is not obvious).

Comment: First of all i tried call ChangeLineFile once i start the program and i did it one time, then closed program and checked the file, there was list with all lines and with changed word then i went back to code and used ChangeLineFile to change another word, then started program and closed, checked the file, another word was changed and previous changed back to default, IDK HOW.

Comment: @Igor, for example at first, content in file looked like this:

Apple
Orange
Lime

First off all i changed Apple to -Apple. Then in project I deleted previous code in which i edited Apple line. Then I used function to change Orange line, I did it and then i opened file to see how two lines were edited, but only one was edited and it is the last one "-Orange".

Comment: Sounds like you are overwriting your file from your project. If you include the file in your project and it is set to copy on build it would overwrite your file every time you execute your app from VS.

Comment: @Igor I tried your code and I can't reproduce the issue. Can you provide step by step instructions of what you did?

Comment: @TamásSzabó - DreDas, not me as I am not the one that asked the question.

Comment: @TamásSzabó, In my project i wrote this line:
ChangeLineInFile(@"Words.txt", @"Words1.txt" ,"Apple", "Apple-");

Then build project and opened the .txt file, Apple line was changed.
Then I went back to project and deleted ChangeLineInFile function and added another:

ChangeLineInFile(@"Words.txt", @"Words1.txt" ,"Orange", "-Orange");
I build it again then opened .txt file, Apple line went back to default and Orange was changed.

Comment: @Igor Fair enough, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

seems to me that your code does the following

```
file1->editA->file2
```

then you run it again. Did you copy file2 back over file1 before you started or did you just do

```
file1->editB->file2
```

After the first pass file1 still has the original data in it. So when you finish the function you need to copy the output file over the input file.

Comment: I made it by these three lines:

`File.Delete(file);
            File.Move(file2, file);
            File.Delete(file2);`

Comment: what you describe should work, but it doesnt, so put your debugging brain on. At then end of the first run does your input file have the new contents. If not - why not.

Answer (score 0):

As I just explained above in the comments.

You are probably including your source file, the file you want to change, in Visual Studio in your project.

- When you run your code from Visual Studio it will copy that source file to the output directory even if there is already a file present from the last execution.
- The original file in your Visual Studio Project is not altered, only the copy that is included with the build output.
- With each execution you are starting with the original file you have included in the project, you are *not* continuing with the file you had changed as this file is overwritten.

That said there are ways that you can specify if you want to include files as output during a build or if they should overwrite an existing file or not. Click on the file in the solution explorer and go to the properties (F4 shortcut on the keyboard). Both the `Build Action` and the `Copy to Output Directory` have to be taken into account.